# lxml XPATH giving all elements instead of just the element under current node

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

The html is like this:

```
<body>
<div class="div_a">
  <ul class="ul">
    <li>li</li>
    <li>li</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="div_b">
  <a>link</a>
  <ul>
    <li>div_b li</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

try to get `div_a`'s li

```
node = page.xpath("//div[@class='div_a']")  
li1 = node.xpath("//li")
```

but li1 got the all li element in page not only div_a's. I cannot figure what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPATH - `//li` - is actually taking elements from the root element, hence you get all `li` . If you want to take only the element inside `node` , you should give relative XPATH. Example -

```
li1 = node.xpath(".//li")
```

`.` in above means current element, which would be the `div` element with `class` attribute as `'div_a'`.

Comment: YES !! Got it ! Andi know . means current element or current folder

Comment: And very thx for you fixed my language problem ^. ^  ( my poor english )
have a nice day~~~

Comment: Glad to be helpful! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Fix your second XPath to be relative instead of absolute as [Anand suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33263603/290085), or simply use a single XPath to get the `li` elements in the first place:

```
li1 = page.xpath("//div[@class='div_a']//li")
```